# RegEx & PHP multiple variabels

Tags: php, regex

For the first time i am busy with Regex with PHP.

I want to make a licenseplate checker and put '-' between the letters and numbers. Everything works for now but the only one problem is that for every string i get another variable.

Like: for 999TB2 i get $1 $2 $3 but the second string 9999XX will be $4 $5 $6. Is it possible to get for the second string also $1 $2 $3?

```html
<?php
$re = '/^(\d{3})([A-Z]{2})(\d{1})|(\d{2})(\d{2})([A-Z]{2})$/';
$str = '9999XX'; //(Will be later connected to database)
$subst = '$1-$2-$3 $4-$5-$6';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;

?>
```

Kind regards

Comment: [Here a different idea](https://tio.run/##LY1BC4JAEIXv@yuGEFTUNrqFiXTr6CFIyohVp1xYXNkdb/132y3n8niP972ZhmlZjmV1rhgLDEIBIb@fstsj@TR900dl4SV2JuFhzgJLxncO7uo6zIHz6CqVghZBCUIDnR5H7Ah7IA29INEKi7ED59aSR4Nd5ob8Mzsrn0wG30@DkxIdRi5O4V/2SiaFfZwz7AYNm8uAsGL6BeTcryhpJqlHkBY223U3Z8vyBQ). It's more generic, not sure if that fits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a branch reset group `(?|` and you can omit `{1}` from the pattern.

```
^(?|(\d{3})([A-Z]{2})(\d)|(\d{2})(\d{2})([A-Z]{2}))$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lg48nW/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/tXRpr).

Example code

```
$strings = [
    "999TB2",
    "9999XX"
];

$re = '/^(?|(\d{3})([A-Z]{2})(\d)|(\d{2})(\d{2})([A-Z]{2}))$/';

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    echo preg_replace($re, '$1-$2-$3', $str) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
999-TB-2
99-99-XX
```